# MySQL column grate that counts number of words that match query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to rate matches based on the number of words from the query that are found in the row. I stared doing this:

```
SELECT Text, MATCH(`Text`) AGAINST ('$s') AS Grade
```

But soon I realised this didn't work since `Grade` is based on a lot of stuff like for example the order the words are, each word's length and so on.

I only want to know the % of words that are present in a row.

EG:

```
$s = 'i want pizza'
`Text` = 'pizza I want' // In this case Grade should be 100 as all words are found
```

Other examples:

```
Text             | Grade
pizza I want too | 100 // All words were found, It doesn't matter if there are extra words
pizza I want     | 100
i want           | 66 // Only 66% of the words are present
want want want   | 33 // Only 33% of the words are present
```

Comment: what about `pizza I want - me too` ? is it 100% too ? what is the metrics for grading ?

Comment: that should be 100% too. I don't care if there are extra words.

Comment: may be [`soundex`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex) helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$s = 'i want pizza';
$text = 'pizza I want';

//move to lower-case to ignore case-differences
$s = strtolower($s);
$text = strtolower($text);

//count the number of words in $s
$slen = count(explode(" ", $s));
//create an array of words from the text that we check
$arr = explode(" ", $text);
$count = 0;
//go over the words from $text and count words that appear on $s
foreach ($arr as $word) {
    if(strpos($s, $word) !== false){
        $count++;
    }
}
//display the percentage in format XX.XX
echo number_format((double)(100 * $count/$slen),2);
```

Comment: I see how it should work for a single row, but I don't see how it could be used to select rows that match the condition unless I run the code individually in each row of the table.

Comment: @Liso22 if you want to apply this code to a large result-set - migrate this code to a store-procedure which calls it in a loop. Otherwise, you can call this code just once upon `INSERT` - which sounds to me more ideally.

Comment: Thanks @alfasin, this is just what I needed for a similar problem!